# How to configure bootpd on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.x)

Tags: mac-osx, bootp

I need to run bootpd on El Capitan and configure it to use a different gateway and modify the pool range by altering file /etc/bootpd.plist

However on El Capitan it seems that bootpd while present is essentially disabled and the bootpd.plist file isn't in /etc or anywhere.

How do I get going with bootpd on 10.11.x ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the content of a:

```
/etc/bootpd.plist
```

which worked correctly on many different versions of MacOS ( Yosemite - High Sierra ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>allow</key>
        <array>
                <string>••:••:••:64:5d:5e</string>

                <string>••:••:••:0b:61:a8</string>
                <string>••:••:••:76:31:48</string>

                <string>••:••:••:9f:20:79</string>
                <string>••:••:••:ed:7c:fd</string>

                <!...>

        </array>
        <key>Subnets</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>_creator</key>
                        <string>com.apple.NetworkSharing</string>
                        <key>allocate</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>dhcp_domain_name_server</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>10.0.2.1</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>dhcp_router</key>
                        <string>10.0.2.1</string>
                        <key>interface</key>
                        <string>en1</string>
                        <key>lease_max</key>
                        <integer>86400</integer>
                        <key>lease_min</key>
                        <integer>86400</integer>
                        <key>name</key>
                        <string>10.0.2/24</string>
                        <key>net_address</key>
                        <string>10.0.2.0</string>
                        <key>net_mask</key>
                        <string>255.255.255.0</string>
                        <key>net_range</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>10.0.2.2</string>
                                <string>10.0.2.31</string>
                        </array>
                </dict>
        </array>
        <key>bootp_enabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>detect_other_dhcp_server</key>
        <array>
                <string>en1</string>
        </array>
        <key>dhcp_enabled</key>
        <array>
                <string>en1</string>
        </array>
        <key>dhcp_ignore_client_identifier</key>
        <true/>
        <key>use_server_config_for_dhcp_options</key>
        <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Next you will have to start the `bootpd` server which is managed
with `launchd`.

See its configuration file here:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist
```

and check if it is running with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo launchctl list com.apple.bootpd
```

Comment: Hi @dan, I am currently facing a similar issue on macos ventura 13.4, I do not see the bootpd running, when I enabled the internet sharing through settings, it automatically creates a file /private/etc/bootpd.list whose contents are similar to yours, but I do not see the service bootp running. Any suggestions, I can provide any logs if needed.

Comment: This other question might help you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49476/22003

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get it to work in Mavericks. No luck so far.

Here are the things I've come across:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150811023904/http://www.jacquesf.com/2011/04/mac-os-x-dhcp-server

http://web.archive.org/web/20150123233315/http://www.iconnectit.nl/?p=29

http://www.redelijkheid.com/blog/2014/8/25/apple-osx-dhcp-server-challenges

[OS X bootpd as dhcp server not giving out ip addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/381404/os-x-bootpd-as-dhcp-server-not-giving-out-ip-addresses)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7025939?start=0

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1209072?start=15&tstart=0

Hopefully some of that helps